# How do I delete the entire list rather than just deleting the elements in the list?

Tags: c

Here are the codes I have to create a list and elements in the list. Now I want to implement a function to delete the entire list rather than just emptying the list. How do I do that?

```
struct node
{
    int number;        
    struct node* next; 
};

struct forward_list
{
    struct node* head;
};

typedef struct node node;

node* create_node(int number, node* next)
{
    node* result = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    result->number = number;
    result->next = next;
    return result;
}


//edit
void destroy_node(node* const this)
{
    free(this);
}
void destroy_list(forward_list* const this)
{
    /* TODO */
}
```

Comment: Since you are allocating the nodes one at a time, you need to free the nodes individually. After that you can set the head to NULL to have an empty list.

Comment: Why would you want to delete a list, if it has already been emptied? Providing an example of the output desired will be helpful.

Comment: Dare I ask, what is your differentiation between an "empty list" and deleting an "entire list" ? How is the latter not the former, and vice versa? if the vernacular is confusing you, just say so. Unrelated, none of the posted code creates a list; the only creation code here creates a *node* (and yes, I'll grand the terminology purists their moment of puffing and concede a single node is, in fact, a list of size one).

Comment: i mean if i empty the list the list is still there right?without anything inside.But deleting the list is completely removing the list so it wont exist anymore

Comment: Well...say you declared a variable like `int a;`. How would you delete it? The closest thing to `removing the list entirely` would be to dynamically allocate the list as well, so that the memory for the list can be freed to be "removed".

Comment: actually this is for a class.Partial codes are given.One of the functions given is to free the nodes but then theres another function to destroy list which i have to fill in.Ill add it into the question

Comment: And again I ask, how is the former not the latter and vice versa? In a non-sentinel managed list scheme, an "empty" list is one that has no nodes (and thus a null head pointer). Destroying all nodes in a linked list and departing with a null head pointer gives you. So what are you *really* talking about? Are you dynamically allocating a `forward_list`, then populating it with a node chain, then destroying the node chain and setting `head` to null, then wondering what to do with the leftover `forward_list` ?

Comment: If you empty a list, the way to do it would be setting `head` to NULL. At this point even if you do not free the nodes, you cannot access the nodes. So you should free the nodes before emptying the list.

Comment: Oh. seeing your edit, I think you just have to call `destroy_node` iteratively in `destroy_list` to empty your list, thus destroying it.

Comment: i see i see.Okay thank you very much.So basically is loop through every node in the list and call destroy_node function everytime?

Comment: Yes, being sure to obtain the current node's `next` pointer value and storing to a temp *before* destroying the current node. Then the temp pointer becomes the new current node pointer, and you repeat the process until the current node pointer becomes `NULL` (in which case you're list is destroyed. When finished, according to the posted utilities, your `this->head` will be NULL and you're done.

Comment: oh but how do i link and get current node's next pointer?Sorry im new to C programming

Comment: I left a possible answer for that. You can check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your edit, I think you just have to call `destroy_node` iteratively in `destroy_list` to empty your list, thus destroying it.

[EDIT]

I had to set the head of the list to `NULL` at the end. Thanks for the comment!

Something like this:

```
void destroy_list(forward_list* const this)
{
    node* temp = this->head;
    node* to_delete;

    while(temp != NULL){
      to_delete = temp;
      temp = temp->next;
      destroy_node(to_delete);
    }
    this->head = NULL;

}
```

Comment: You should also set `this->head = NULL` at the end,

Comment: @RishikeshRaje inside or outside the while loop?

Comment: Oh thanks :) I've added it! FYI, it would still work without setting the head to NULL, but it's a brilliant precaution to set `this->head = NULL`.